# How to evaluate which page to show in PostConstruct?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Imagine this situation:

I have a SessionScoped bean (named `TheSessionBean`) that is a ManagedProperty of another bean (named `AnotherBean`).

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AnotherBean implements Serializable {

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    //Evaluate here!
}

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{theSessionBean}")
private TheSessionBean theSessionBean;
    //Getter and Setter...
}
```

I need to evaluate the value of the ManagedProperty (`theSessionBean`) **in order to know if a page can be showed without the user interaction and before the page is shown**.

As I understand this must be evaluated in the PostConstruct method (so I can get the value of the Session of the ManagedProperty).

`TheSessionBean` has only a String property named permission.

So first of all I need to know if:

- `theSessionBean.getPermission() == null` in order to redirect to a page named `one`
- `theSessionBean.getPermission().equals("two")` in order to redirect to a page named `two`
- `More evaluations...`

**The problem is that the PostConstruct method must be void and I need to redirect to the corresponding page.**

How can I do that?

Comment: Isn't it better to use the built in security for whichever technology you are using (is it Spring or full JEE)? Otherwise, is it enough to set a boolean property which can be used to choose how to display the page? Using `FacesContext` to make a programmatic redirect in `@PostConstruct` doesn't really make sense to me, if even possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ExternalContext.redirect` in your `PostConstruct` method.

```
if (someCondition)) {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/one");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use JSF system events- PreRenderViewEvent PostConstructApplicationEvent PreDestroyApplicationEvent
[JSF events](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_applicationevents_tag.htm)